# Probability of choosing two balls of same/different colors

Tags: probability

> There is a box with different balls in it. 5 are white, 2 are black and 3 are red. We take 2 balls from the bag simultaneously. What is the probability that the two of them are white? What is the probability that the two of them have different colors?

To guess the probability of the two that are white, I tried taking the probability that the white balls have 5/10, red has 3/10 and black have 2/10.
For the two of them to be in the same color I did 5/10 * 4/9 = 20/90 = 2/9
Is this the correct way and how would I calculate if they are of different colors because the 3 different colors are confusing me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of the probability that both are white is correct:$$P(W_1\cap W_2)=P(W_1)P(W_2\mid W_1)=\frac5{10}\frac49$$

Hint:

$$P(\text{different colors})=1-P(\text{both white})-P(\text{both black})-P(\text{both red})$$